# Rails 7 seed image inside rich text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

on rails 7 with active storage

In a model Lesson, I have an rich text: description

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :description
```

I try to seed 'description' from a previous application where description was html.
this html content image tag was like that:

```
Loremypsem <h2><img src=\"https://www.my-web-site.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Image-SketchUp-Pro-2019.png\"
    alt=\"\" /></h2>
```

Image where coming from wordpress.

I want to upload them (no pb for me) and store them into the rich text description.

I don't know how to seed rich text.